# Excel - how to drag down formula while keeping horizontal cell reference continuity

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I been trying few formulas and google search, but wasn't able to find anything that would help my problem. To keep it simple, as explained in the attached picture, how do I drag down formula vertically, while continue the horizontal cell reference in the formula

[image: screenshot here]?

As in picture - formula vertical direction - green arrow, while following the horizontal cells - orange arrow.

Thank you a million!

Comment: Why don't you fill in your table with some expected results so that it's clearer?

Comment: Thanks yea I wanted to keep it simpler, but I guess I should have done that from the start. Anyway I find offset solution which is not perfect on its own, but it does work, cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `OFFSET` function in order to specify a cell offset from cell `A1`. Even if the formula is being copied downward, this can still be a horizontal offset. For example, the following formula inserted into cell `B2` in your screenshot will offset to the right when it is copied downward (it uses the numbers in column A as the offset values):

```
=OFFSET($A$1, 0, A2)
```

Comment: This worked great too, thank you bdr9!

Comment: @Tanukiarecool You're welcome! I see that you asked about inserting new columns. When you insert a column, if you change the `$A$1` in the formula to always point to the cell directly to the left of the first column heading, it will continue to work.

Comment: is there a way to increase column offset values automatically in perpetuity (+1) as I drag it down vertically instead of pointing to vertical cell values?

Comment: @Tanukiarecool You can replace the `A2` with `ROW()-1`. This means that the row number that the formula is in will be used as the offset (after subtracting 1 from it).

Answer (score 1):

A non-volatile suggestion with Index:

```
=A2-INDEX($1:$1,ROW(A2))
```

Offset is volatile and will cause the whole workbook to recalculate any time any cell is changed. That can lead to slowness in larger files with many formulas.

Explanation (after request for clarification):

The first row has data starting in column B, which is the 2nd column. The Index() function above looks at the entire row 1 and then gets pointed to the second column because the function Row(A2) returns the value `2`.

If the formula is dragged down, the `Row(A2)` bit changes to `Row(A3)` and the number `3` is returned, hence Index will return the third column of row 1.

To adjust this scenario to another setting you need to inspect the setup. Which column in row 1 has the first data value? The second, the third, or the nth column?

The column number with the first value is what you need for the number part in the reference for the Row() function. If your data starts in column 2, then it will be `Row(A2)`. If your data starts in column 7 then it will need to be `Row(A7)`. Then drag down to let Excel do its thing with adjusting relative references.

The important bit is that you get the starting number right.

Comment: Thank you this worked like a peanut-butter banana sandwich!

Comment: Hi teylyn, actually I have follow up question, but since I couldn't attached screenshot to commentary I posted it below as an answer. Can you please have a look ad advise how to go abut it? Thank you!

Comment: Oh now I see how this works, actually I wasn't looking for this. I need function to do row value-column value and so that function variable is increasing both directions along column (drag down) and across columns (increasing along row) as you drag the function down the vertical column. Now I understood that what index did was point to a number specified as value in a cell in the vertical column. The reason it worked for me initially was because my original example had that both vertical and horizontal values cross pointing to themselves, but once I added extra it stopped working as intended

Comment: ROWS is preferable to ROW in these types of constructions, since it is not adversely affected by row insertions within the worksheet. For example, the difference between =A2-INDEX($1:$1,ROW(A2)) and =A2-INDEX($1:$1,ROWS($1:2)) is seen after inserting a row above row 1. The ROW construction will no longer give correct results, whereas that using ROWS will. Perhaps some might argue that this is a small point, but in my experience row inserting is quite a common action in practice, and so we should guard against it where possible.

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is done by anchoring the portion of the address you want fixed (row and/or column), by prefixing it with `$`.  So if you want to drag your formula down and have the next cell be `=A3-B1`, what you want fixed is the row 1 reference in column B.  You would make the B2 cell formula `=A2-B$1`.  When you drag that down in the same column, the A2 reference will increment but not the B1 reference.

If you want to be able to drag across, so the next cell to the right would contain `=A2-C1`, it is the column A reference you want to lock.  The formula in your first cell would `=$A2-B1`.

If you want to drag both horizontally and vertically to populate the whole table in this fashion, the first cell would be `=$A2-B$1`.  As you move *horizontally*, the only thing that will change is the column B reference.  Moving *vertically*, the only thing that will change is the row 2 reference.

Comment: Thank you, I am familiar with fixing the cells. Here I was going more for solution similar to what teylyn and bdr9 provided. Thank you anyway, a very good suggestion for people looking for fixing the cells.