# Maintaining a Horizontal Reference when doing multiple sums Vertically

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

As my question says, I'm trying to drag a sum formula downwards down rows  with the reference cells extending across columns.

This example best illustrates

[image]

I'm trying to get the summed monthly revenue for each year in a seperate set of cells.

Doing `=SUM(B10:M10)` works for the single year 2020, but when I try to do this for the year 2021 and drag down Excel opts for `=SUM(B11:M11)` instead of `=SUM(N10:Y10)` as I would wish.

[This answer](https://superuser.com/questions/989533/excel-how-to-drag-down-formula-while-keeping-horizontal-cell-reference-continu) previously suggested using the `OFFSET` command. When I try this using the command `=SUM((OFFSET(B$10:M$10,0,0,12)))`, I still get the same value of 78. What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use INDEX to set the range:

```
=SUM(INDEX($10:$10,,(ROW($ZZ1)-1)*12+2):INDEX($10:$10,,(ROW($ZZ1)-1)*12+13))
```

The first Index as it is dragged down will return B10,N10,...

And the second will return M10,Y10,...

Thus setting the extents of the sum

[image]

---

Another option is if the dates in row 9 are true dates then one can use SUMIFS:

```
=SUMIFS($10:$10,$9:$9,">="&DATE(A1,1,1),$9:$9,"<"&DATE(A1+1,1,1))
```

This bookends the dates based on the year in the A colum.

[image]

Comment: Thanks ! This works perfectly, though I am amazed something so 'simple' requires such a complex solution. I do have one question, I get that the `=(ROW($ZZ1)-1)` generates 0,1,2, .. for each row dragged down: could I ask why ?

Comment: `$ZZ` is just an arbitrary column I like that I know will not have data, to avoid unnecessary calculations.  I could have use `$A1` just as easily.  The point it the row number `1`, it makes sure that where ever you put the first formula the count always starts at `0`.  If I used `ROW()` by itself and you put it in row 15 first, then it would start at `14` not `0`.  And we need to start at `0` to make the math correct.

Comment: Ah that's what I thought but thanks for coming back !